# How to concatenate strings in Java?

Tags: java

The `strKeyword` will be repeated according to the loop. How can I Save the outcome as a new string. For example if the work "hello" was repeated twice, how would I now create the "hellohello" as a completely new string.

```
for (int l = 0; l < newKeywordLength; l++) {          
    System.out.print(strKeyword);
}
```

Comment: Eclipse has something to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string newWord="";
for (int l=0; l<newKeywordLength; l++){           
         newWord+=strKeyword;
}
System.out.print(newWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use

strKeyword+=strKeyword;

since java 6 well optimized, no need for a stringbuilder

Comment: You got the one up for the advice that the compiler will optimize this starting with java 6.